# Ionic PWA cordova.js missing

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I deployed the browser version (progressive web app) of my Ionic 2 project to Heroku but I'm not able to access any of Cordova's plugins, I get the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) - cordova.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Cordova plugins in the browser. Their purpose is to provide access to native mobile device capabilities. If you are building your project as a PWA you need to make use of the ionic core APIs as much as possible in place of Ionic Native/cordova plugins.

This is useful background from Ionic: 
http://blog.ionic.io/what-is-a-progressive-web-app/